# Magento 2 - checkout page loading but not stoping

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, payment-methods

[image]

when ever i click next for check out page

some time still loading

some times shows empty page

How i can fix this....

Comment: Did you checked console error ?

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.paypal.com/xoplatform/logger/api/logger. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.paypal.com/xoplatform/logger/api/logger. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)